# Certbot: Invalid response http://www.example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge

Tags: python, django, nginx, certbot

[image]

I'm working through https://serversforhackers.com/video/letsencrypt-for-free-easy-ssl-certificates and https://certbot.eff.org/docs/intro.html , trying to add  an ssl certificate to my site (django 1.8 on nginx on ubuntu 16.04). I have been able to do this before a few months ago using the standalone option ([Certbot cannot reach nginx webroot running django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164186/certbot-cannot-reach-nginx-webroot-running-django)), but this time I want to get the certbot-auto script working so I can run it on a chron job. I tried:

```
deploy@server:/opt/certbot$ sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html -d example.org -d www.example.org
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.org
http-01 challenge for www.example.org
Using the webroot path /var/www/html for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.example.org (http-01): urn:acme:erruthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response http://www.example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/6j3QzM4LGMRWaLYZXYTR98: "
```

If I paste http://www.example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/6j3QzM4LGMRWaLYZXYTR98: " into the browser I get a 404 like in the screenshot. Is it possible to set django to allow the challenge to 'pass through ' the routing without generating a django error?

EDIT:

please note I am NOT running from root but rather a normal user (deploy)

output of nginx -T:

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example3:
server {
    #listen 80;
    listen 80  ;
    listen [::]:80  ;
    listen 443 ssl http2  ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2  ;


    server_name  example.org www.example.org;
    include snippets/ssl-example.org.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf; 

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/deploy/example3;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/example3.sock;
    }


    location ~* (?:^|/)\.  {
        allow all;
    }

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-example.org.conf:
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf:
# from https://cipherli.st/
# and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params:

uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Comment: It seems like django feels responsible for the request, so nginx isn't configured correctly. I would check the config.

Comment: Can you tell me for what?

Comment: The `nginx` snippet you give should work. Use `nginx -T` to check what `nginx` is actually using

Comment: please see edit: